# MySQL Query Optimisation of Sort and Group

Tags: mysql, sorting, optimization

I have a query like this...

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE area3, area, area2, COUNT( area ) AS total
FROM wpthillsdatabase
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY area3 ASC , area ASC
```

Its EXPLAIN says it is using filesort, none of the indexes and a temp table...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  wpthillsdatabaseV12 ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9334    Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Is it possible to optimise this further to remove the filesort or the temp table with an index or is this as good as it gets?

FYI The TABLE is structured like this...

```
CREATE TABLE `wpthillsdatabase` (
  `hillnumber` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
  `wikipedia` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `hillname` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `meters` char(6) NOT NULL default '',
  `GridZN` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `GridEast` char(5) NOT NULL default '',
  `GridNorth` char(5) NOT NULL default '',
  `numeast` char(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `numnorth` char(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `areadecimal` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `area` varchar(3) NOT NULL default '',
  `area2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `maps` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `waypointname` char(6) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL default '',
  `latitude` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL default '0.00000000',
  `longitude` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL default '0.0000000',
  `area3` smallint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dip` decimal(5,1) NOT NULL default '0.0' COMMENT 'col height (m)',
  `climbedbytotal` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `trigID` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
  `trigEast` varchar(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `trigNorth` varchar(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `trigLat` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `trigLon` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `SummitInfo` varchar(290) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`hillnumber`,`area3`),
  UNIQUE KEY `meters` (`meters`,`hillnumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SortIndex1` (`hillnumber`,`hillname`,`meters`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NearByHills` (`numeast`,`numnorth`,`hillnumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hillnumber_only` (`hillnumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Area3_Sort` (`area3`,`hillnumber`,`hillname`,`meters`),
  UNIQUE KEY `GirdZN_sort` (`GridZN`,`hillnumber`,`hillname`,`meters`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hil_lat_lon` (`hillnumber`,`latitude`,`longitude`),
  KEY `trigID` (`trigID`,`hillname`,`meters`),
  KEY `climbedbytotal` (`climbedbytotal`),
  KEY `hillname` (`hillname`,`meters`),
  KEY `area3` (`area3`,`hillnumber`),
  KEY `hillname_only` (`hillname`),
  KEY `area3_trigID` (`area3`,`trigID`),
  KEY `Area_text` (`area`,`area3`),
  KEY `dip_area3` (`dip`,`area3`),
  KEY `lat_lon` (`latitude`,`longitude`,`meters`),
  KEY `trigID_area3` (`trigID`,`area3`),
  KEY `numeast_north` (`numeast`,`numnorth`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

Ta
```

phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your request implies :

- `GROUP BY area` can be optimized using an index starting with `area`
- `ORDER BY are3 ASC, area ASC` can be optimized using an index starting with `area3, area`

but no index can be used to optimize both bits at the same time.

If you can afford to change your result, try changing the sort order : `ORDER BY area ASC, area3 ASC`.

As [bobwienholt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917795/86072) suggested, you can test a covering index on your table to at least optimize the extraction of the `GROUP` table, but the index should start with `area` : `KEY myKey (area, area3, area2)`.

However, if your table becomes big and is frequently updated, multiplying indexes (especially when they encompass `varchar(100)` columns) can hinder performances if your table is frequently updated. Depending on the cases, you are better off extracting unsorted data from mysql, and filter/sort them in your server code ( php / ruby / python ... )

Comment: Hi, thanks that is really useful, i hadn't realised that. If my table has one column ('`climbedbytotal`') that IS frequently updated but does not appear in this query, nor in any of the indexes, does this cause a performace issue?

Comment: You should remove any single column indexes where you never search on that value. It is a waste of space and does make updates and inserts slower.  Don't get scared off by statements like "indexes slow down updates"... unless you are updating your tables like crazy, the performance benefit on SELECT will far outweigh any update performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn "Area_text" into a covering index by adding the area2 column to the end.  Not sure if it would help with optimizing the GROUP BY or ORDER BY but it would allow MySQL to use just that index to process the query which should speed it up a bit.